# Raritan serial consoles (DSX) totally unreliable

Tags: serial

We have some serial consoles by manufacturer Raritan.

More specifically, 8-port and 16-port DSX-8 and DSX-16s.

Currently, I seriously doubt their stability.

**What happens most of the time:**

Usually, the device isn't needed for some time.

When it is finally needed, I connect to it via ssh and give it the (serial) port number to connect to.

Upon that action it just reboots. And it takes ages (10+ minutes) to reboot. (During a network problem where the console is needed urgently that simply is not tolerable.)

Firmware is up to date.

**Support** is of no use at all. ("Would you like us to send a replacement?")

(No all of them are doing it.)

**Does someone use those Raritan devices?**

Either there is something inherently wrong with them or we are doing something consistently wrong.

I seriously consider switching to more serious devices.

Comment: I myself found Raritan products generally good and its support certainly above average, really good actually. Of course this only my own experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We gave the old DSXs the benefit of the doubt and now have some DSX2s. While they IMHO still have some minor deficiencies (like Java being used and some other minor annoyances during configuration) they seem to keep the road a lot better than the old models. They are really faster and more stable so far (just hoping that the larger memory doesn't simply compensate for the memory leaks and stuff) :)

Comment: Hey, they really contacted us a while ago if we wanted to have the latest interim firmware where apparently the original issue has been fixed. So we were not crazy after all, but apparently carried not enough weight to make them believe that a problem existed in the first place...